# Functional equivalent of this loop

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to refactor the following function to make it more Kotlin-idiomatic using modern functional language features:

```
fun foobar(): List<Account> {
    var pageOffset = 0
    val accounts: MutableList<Account> = ArrayList()
    var chunk: List<Account> = accountsService.getAccounts(pageOffset, MAX_POLL_SIZE)
    while (chunk.isNotEmpty()) {
        accounts.addAll(chunk)
        pageOffset += MAX_POLL_SIZE
        chunk = accountsService.getAccounts(pageOffset, MAX_POLL_SIZE)
    }
    return accounts
}
```

My first attempt was to replace the mutable list with buildList, but it's still not quite functional style:

```
fun foobar2(): List<Account> {
    var pageOffset = 0
    return buildList {
        var chunk: List<Account> = accountsService.getAccounts(pageOffset, MAX_POLL_SIZE)
        while (chunk.isNotEmpty()) {
            addAll(chunk)
            pageOffset += MAX_POLL_SIZE
            chunk = accountsService.getAccounts(pageOffset, MAX_POLL_SIZE)
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to replace the whole `while` loop with something like `accountsService.getAccounts(...).map { ... }` but I can't figure out how to refactor a while loop that has this kind of "first chunk" followed by a number of further chunks. Can it be done?

Comment: Try using [fold](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) Ideally in pure functional programming `map` would be side effect free, so trying to mutate a variable doesn't fit in. With `fold` you can have an accumulator to keep track of that extra logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
fun foobar(): List<Account> =
    generateSequence(0) { it + MAX_POLL_SIZE }.map { offset ->
        accountsService.getAccounts(offset, MAX_POLL_SIZE)
    }.takeWhile { it.isNotEmpty() }.flatten().toList()
```

[`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) generates an infinite, lazy sequence starting with `0`, `MAX_POLL_SIZE`, `MAX_POLL_SIZE * 2`, `MAX_POLL_SIZE * 3`, and so on. This is the sequence of page offsets for which you are getting accounts. We transform each page offset to the list of accounts it corresponds to, using `map`. After that, we specify an end to the infinite sequence using [`takeWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/take-while.html).

Now we have a `Sequence<List<Account>>`, so we use [`flatten`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/flatten.html) converts that into a `Sequence<Account>`, which can then be trivially converted to a `List<Account>`,

Comment: Shouldn't the generateSequence(0) closure check for it being 0? Like this: _{ it + (if (it == 0) 0 else MAX_POLL_SIZE) }_. Without this the first _getAccounts_ would not be called with 0, but with MAX_POLL_SIZE.

Comment: @lukas.j `generateSequence(0) { it + 1}` for example generates `[0,1,2,...]`, not `[1,2,3,...]`. The answer here is correct

Comment: @lukas.j No? The seed is the first element. `println(generateSequence(0) { it + 10 }.take(10).toList())` prints `[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]`.